# Eclipse project root equivalent to Axis2.war

Tags: apache-axis

I have multiple non-jar resources to load within an aar file of Axis2.war.

Most of them are successfully loaded using configuration table where absolute path of

each resource(text files) is specified.

But I have an open-source-based jar that loads resource at the root path(??)

of Eclipse project which is at the same level of "src" folder.

When the classes of the project above are jarred into a lib of aar,

the resources has no way of being read by the class that needs it.

I've put them just outside of aar, within the lib of aar or at the same level of the lib.

They just don't work.

Please remember that this is the case where getResourceStream or something like that

can't be used, because the jar has hard coded the path to be located at the root path of

a project of Eclipse.

Then my question is where the Eclipse-project-root-path-equivalent in Axis2.war which is

deployed in JBoss 5.1.

I am not sure if this question is understood, but please give a bit of advice.

//

Referential images that describe the situation above can be found at

https://community.jboss.org/thread/221937

Answer (score 0):

I used System.getProperty("user.dir") to find exactly where the jar refers to the resources and in

my case C:\Users\MYUSERACCOUNT\Development\server\jboss5.1\server\default\deploy\axis2.w‌​‌​ar\WEB-

INF\services MYUSERACCOUNT is the root of an AAR in Axis2.war service folder. So I placed the

required resource folder within my account folder ( Windows 7 ) and it worked